# Why does the facebook app ticker say [My Name] is using Untitled Page

Tags: facebook, ticker

Ive created a simple facebook canvas app with the title set in the head but when i access the app through facebook i get an entry in the app ticker on the right saying ive started using Untitled Page.

Please can you tell me what im doing wrong.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps, edit your application settings. In Basic settings you will find "App Display Name:". Add your application name here. That will be displayed in the ticker.